# Multiply a number so that it's always in the thousand billions

Tags: multiple-integral

Excuse my lack of mathematical notation, hopefully this makes sense.

Say I have a number which is `x`

`10,000,000,000,000 > x > 999,999,999`

I always want to multiply this number by some other number `y`, so that the result `z` in the thousand billions, so for example:

```
x = 1,230,000,000      
x * y = z
z = 1,230,000,000,000
y = 1000

x = 55,123,000,000      
x * y = z
z = 5,512,300,000,000
y = 100

x = 456,123,000,000      
x * y = z
z = 4,561,230,000,000
y = 10

x = 7,894,560,000,000      
x * y = z
z = 7,894,560,000,000
y = 1
```

All I have is `x` and the I know that `x` is be between  `1,000,000,000` and `9,999,999,999,999`.

How can I find the value of `y` so that I can calculate `z`? I'm currently doing this manually (in code) with if statements,

```
if x < 10 => x * 1000
if x < 100 => x * 100
if x < 1000 => x * 10
if x < 1000 => x
```

But I'm looking for a single mathematical function that can do this for me.

**Solved with Arnaud Mortier's answer**

Using the marked answer I created the function (in Javascript)

```
const fn = x => {
    let k = 12 - Math.floor(Math.log10(x));
    let y = Math.pow(10, k);
    let z = x * y;

    console.log(`x = ${x}, k = ${k}, y = ${y}, z = ${z}`);

    return z;
};
```

Even more than I hoped for, this works for *any* positive integer, not just those in my range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $y=10^{k}$. \begin{align}10^{12}\leq z<10^{13}&\Longleftrightarrow 12\leq {\log_{10}(x\cdot 10^k)}<13\\&\Longleftrightarrow \left\lfloor \log_{10}{(x\cdot 10^k)}\right\rfloor=12\\&\Longleftrightarrow \left\lfloor \log_{10}{(x)+k}\right\rfloor=12\\&\Longleftrightarrow k=12-\left\lfloor \log_{10}{(x)}\right\rfloor\\\end{align}

If you don't have $\log_{10}$ implemented in your computer, use $\log_{10}(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(10)}$.

The function $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$ is usually implemented as [$\operatorname{floor}(x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Comment: Thanks, going to give this one a go. All x are integers so I won't be needing the `floor`

Comment: @JamesHay You will most likely need the floor function after you apply log.

Comment: Oh my god, that completely worked! Thanks heaps.

Comment: @JamesHay You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a number $k$ between one thousand billion and ten thousand billion and take $y = \frac{k}{x}$ ?

Comment: If you look at the examples, the OP wants $y$ to be a power of $10$.

Answer (score 0):

Writing $x$ in scientific notation we get something like $k\times10^n$ where $1<k<9$. For example $x = 1,230,000,000 = 1.23\times10^9$ Now you want the $z = 1,230,000,000,000=1.23\times10^{12}$. So you need to multiply $1000$ or $10^3$.  Just find the value $n$ when $x$ is written in scientific notation and if see how much you are short of $12$. And multiply that much.